# Populate inorder successor for all nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

> Given a binary tree where each node has following structure, write a
>   function to populate next pointer for all nodes. The next pointer for
>   every node should be set to point to inorder successor.
>
> ```
> struct node
> {
>   int data;
>   struct node* left;
>   struct node* right;
>   struct node* next;
> }
> ```
>
> Initially, all next pointers have NULL values. Your function should
>   fill these next pointers so that they point to inorder successor.

This code is attributed to GeeksForGeeks. Looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
public class PopulateInorderSuccessor<T> {

    private TreeNode<T> root;

    public PopulateInorderSuccessor(List<T> items) {
        create (items);
    }

    private void create(List<T> items) {
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There should atlease be single item in the tree");
        }

        root = new TreeNode<>(items.get(0));

        final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(left));
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(right));
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TreeNode<T> {
        private TreeNode<T> left;
        private T item;
        private TreeNode<T> right;
        private TreeNode<T> next;

        TreeNode(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    private static class TreeNodeHolder<T> {
        private TreeNode<T> treeNode;
    }

    public void populateInorderSuccessor() {
        populate(root, new TreeNodeHolder<T>());
    }

    private void populate(TreeNode<T> node, TreeNodeHolder<T> treeNodeHolder) {
        if (node != null) {
            populate(node.right, treeNodeHolder);
            node.next = treeNodeHolder.treeNode;
            treeNodeHolder.treeNode = node;
            populate(node.left, treeNodeHolder);
        }
    }

    public List<T> toInOrderList() {
        TreeNode<T> node = root;

        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }

        final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (node != null) {
            list.add(node.item);
            node = node.next;
        }
        return list;
    }
}


public class PopulateInorderSuccessorTest {

    @Test
    public void testCompleteTree() {
        PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis1 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        pis1.populateInorderSuccessor();        
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7), pis1.toInOrderList());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLeftSkewedTree() {
        // left skewed
        PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis2 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, 4));
        pis2.populateInorderSuccessor();        
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 1), pis2.toInOrderList());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRightSkewedTree() {
        // right skewed
        PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis3 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, null, 3, null, null, null, 7));
        pis3.populateInorderSuccessor();        
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 7), pis3.toInOrderList());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does an 'in-order successor' mean?

Comment: @rolfl generally "in-order" is a way of flattening a tree that basically outputs the left sub tree, then the node, then the right sub tree. Obviously the in-order successor would be the successor of the current node in the hypothetical list caused by flattening the tree.

Comment: @raptortech97 - I don't doubt you on this, but in-order could also mean by some comparator order, by depth-first traversal order (node before, or after, or between), by breadth-first order, etc. Without a reference to this, there is no way to tell whether the code works.

Answer (score 6):

I think this equivalent, but simpler. It removes the need for the `TreeNodeHolder` class by returning a `TreeNode<T>`.

```
public void populateInorderSuccessor() {
  populate(root, null);
}

private TreeNode<T> populate(TreeNode<T> root, TreeNode<T> successor) {
  if (root == null) {
    return successor;
  }

  root.next = populate(root.right, successor);
  return populate(root.left, root);
}
```

---

`PopulateInorderSuccessor` is not a good name for a class. Let's change it to `BinaryTree`.

---

Tree construction can be simplified:

```
public BinaryTree(T[] items) {
  this.root = create(items, 0);
}

private TreeNode<T> create(T[] items, int i) {
  if (i >= items.length || items[i] == null) {
    return null;
  }

  TreeNode<T> root = new TreeNode<T>(items[i]);
  root.left = create(items, 2 * i + 1);
  root.right = create(items, 2 * i + 2);
  return root;
}
```

---

I find that helper methods `setLeft` and `setRight` on `TreeNode` can make tree code a bit cleaner, in general. It's not of much advantage here, but just for reference:

```
public TreeNode<T> setLeft(TreeNode<T> left) {
  this.left = left;
  return this;
}

public TreeNode<T> setRight(TreeNode<T> right) {
  this.right = right;
  return this;
}
```

This way we can write

```
private TreeNode<T> create(T[] items, int i) {
  if (i >= items.length || items[i] == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return new TreeNode<T>(items[i])
    .setLeft(create(items, 2 * i + 1))
    .setRight(create(items, 2 * i + 2));
}
```

---

Putting it all together, we get something like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BinaryTree<T> {
  private TreeNode<T> root;

  public BinaryTree(T[] items) {
    this.root = create(items, 0);
  }

  private TreeNode<T> create(T[] items, int i) {
    if (i >= items.length || items[i] == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return new TreeNode<T>(items[i])
      .setLeft(create(items, 2 * i + 1))
      .setRight(create(items, 2 * i + 2));
  }

  public void populateInorderSuccessor() {
    populate(root, null);
  }

  private TreeNode<T> populate(TreeNode<T> root, TreeNode<T> successor) {
    if (root == null) {
      return successor;
    }

    root.next = populate(root.right, successor);
    return populate(root.left, root);
  }

  public List<T> toInOrderList() {
    TreeNode<T> node = root;
    while (node.left != null) {
      node = node.left;
    }

    final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (node != null) {
      list.add(node.item);
      node = node.next;
    }
    return list;
  }

  private static class TreeNode<T> {
    private TreeNode<T> left;
    private T item;
    private TreeNode<T> right;
    private TreeNode<T> next;

    TreeNode(T item) {
      this.item = item;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> setLeft(TreeNode<T> left) {
      this.left = left;
      return this;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> setRight(TreeNode<T> right) {
      this.right = right;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you create the tree from a flat list is cryptic, hard to use, not intuitive.
If I look hard, I can figure out that from a list like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` it fills the tree level by level like this:

```
       1
   2       3
 4   5   6   7
```

But I have to look hard. If I want to make specific trees, for example this:

```
       1
   2       3
 4           7
```

I have to visualize the complete layout or do some math to figure out the right indexes to put `null` in the list. This gets even more confusing if I want to use node items with values that don't correspond to their indexes, for example as in this unbalanced binary tree:

```
       4
   2       6
             7
               15
```

Even if I manage to calculate the correct indexes, I might make a mistake in counting the indexes when writing the parameter list. For example, is it obvious which of these is correct for the above tree:

- 4, 2, 6, null, null, null, 7, null, null, null, null, null, null, 15
- 4, 2, 6, null, null, null, 7, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 15

Sure, it's the second one, because there have to be 15 elements,
but you have to count that carefully, and it's pretty annoying.
Adding another level would be even worse.

To remedy that, I propose these helper methods:

```
public static <T> TreeNode<T> newNode(T item, TreeNode<T> left, TreeNode<T> right) {
    return new TreeNode<>(item, left, right);
}

public static <T> TreeNode<T> newNode(T item) {
    return new TreeNode<>(item, null, null);
}

static class TreeNode<T> {
    // ...

    public TreeNode(T item, TreeNode<T> left, TreeNode<T> right) {
        this.item = item;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public PopulateInorderSuccessor(TreeNode<T> root) {
    this.root = root;
}
```

This way your unit tests become a lot easier to read:

```
@Test
public void testCompleteTree() {
    //PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis1 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
    PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis1 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(
            PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(1,
                    PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(2, PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(4), PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(5)),
                    PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(3, PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(6), PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(7)))
    );
    pis1.populateInorderSuccessor();
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7), pis1.toInOrderList());
}

@Test
public void testLeftSkewedTree() {
    // left skewed
    //PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis2 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, 4));
    PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis2 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(
            PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(1,
                    PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(2, PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(4), null),
                    null)
    );
    pis2.populateInorderSuccessor();
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 1), pis2.toInOrderList());
}

@Test
public void testRightSkewedTree() {
    // right skewed
    //PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis3 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, null, 3, null, null, null, 7));
    PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer> pis3 = new PopulateInorderSuccessor<Integer>(
            PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(1,
                    null,
                    PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(3, null, PopulateInorderSuccessor.newNode(7)))
    );
    pis3.populateInorderSuccessor();
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 7), pis3.toInOrderList());
}
```

The cryptic `create` method is not needed anymore, you can focus on the main problem.

These unit tests are a lot easier to both write and to read.
It may seem like they are more typing, but with any decent IDE that's a non-issue.
And you can write more confidently,
because the structure of the tree is visible right in the test itself,
you don't have to think where list elements might be going.

Code is read far more times than it’s written.
Favor techniques that speed up read-time.